# Regex to get any uppercase letter within a slug without query parameters

Tags: ruby, regex, url

There are quite few solutions how to get query parameters, however I would like grab url without query parameters only if that matches any uppercase letter

So here is my REGEX to grab uppercase letters, however I don't have any to grab URL without parameters,

`([B-Z]|A[^_]|A$)`

Example:

```
localhost:8080/my-UrL/url?auth-token=AdfsfasdfsdjfkladjaDSfl # should match => "my-UrL/url"
```

```
localhost:8080/my-url/url?auth-token=AdfsfasdfsdjfkladjaDSfl # should match => nil`
```

```
localhost:8080/my-url/URL?auth-token=AdfsfasdfsdjfkladjaDSfl # should match => "my-url/URL"
```

Answer (score 1):

`\\/([\\w\\/-]*[A-Z][\\w\\/-]*)(?:\\?|$)`

This matches your examples:

```
irb(main):012:0> r = Regexp.new "\\/([\\w\\/-]*[A-Z][\\w\\/-]*)(?:\\?|$)"
irb(main):013:0> r.match "localhost:8080/mY-url/url?asdasd"
=> #<MatchData "/mY-url/url?" 1:"mY-url/url">
```

Comment: This could more easily be written as `%r{/([\w/-]*[A-Z][\w/-]*)(?:\?|$)}` - less escaping...

Answer (score 1):

The required regex is:

```
/(?<=0\/).*[A-Z]+.*(?=\?)/
```

Explaining the regex:
`(?<=0\/)` is a negative lookahead assertion which ensures that `"0/"` is matched but not included in the matched characters
`(?=\?)` is a positive lookahead assertion which ensures that `"?"` is matched but not included in the matched characters
`.*[A-Z]+.*` ensures that string matched should include one or more uppercase characters

```
"localhost:8080/my-UrL/url?auth-token=AdfsfasdfsdjfkladjaDSfl".match /(?<=0\/).*[A-Z]+.*(?=\?)/
 => #<MatchData "my-UrL/url"> 
 "localhost:8080/my-url/url?auth-token=AdfsfasdfsdjfkladjaDSfl".match /(?<=0\/).*[A-Z]+.*(?=\?)/
 => nil 
"localhost:8080/my-url/URL?auth-token=AdfsfasdfsdjfkladjaDSfl".match /(?<=0\/).*[A-Z]+.*(?=\?)/
 => #<MatchData "my-url/URL">
```